# C++ Returning value of a register after executing an instruction at a specific address

Tags: c++, memory, assembly, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to read the value of a register at a certain stage of execution.
For instance:
The register ESI is set to a value by an insn at 0x80487a0.

My code to get the value of ESI is:

```
__asm{
    mov dword ptr [pBasePointer],esi
};
```

but the value of ESI has been set to something different when this code is ran, I need to get the value of ESI when its set at 0x80487a0

Any insight?

Comment: Could you explain a bit more? Registers aren't in any addresses and if ESI is 2, its value is 2.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen The register ESI is being set several other times afterwords, I want to get the value of ESI as it is at a certain point in memory

Comment: Is this CheatEngine related?

Comment: @MichaelPetch I found where the value of ESI was being set in OllyDbg via breakpoints, However thats irrelevant to my question. I need to be able to programatically get the value of ESI as its set at a specific address in memory from C++ / ASM

Comment: I ask the question because as it is written it makes no sense. ESI doesn't have a value at a specific memory location. I ask about cheat-engine because I have seen almost identical questions worded the same way and it usually comes down to the way cheat-engine words things. If this was cheat-engine related I would have added the tag.

Comment: @MichaelPetch The register values are being changed, Im not implying that the register is static to that address, I just want to get the value after its changed at that address. I am not sure how ASM is ran through C++, but by the time that my ASM code is ran, the value of ESI is different to what it is being set to at this address.

Comment: Do you mean changed by an instruction at address 0x2?  Like, instead of setting a breakpoint at 0x00002, you want to trigger something every time execution runs an instruction at that address?  Note that `2` is an extremely unlikely address.

Comment: @PeterCordes Yes, in a way, I want to get the value of the ESI register after the instruction happens at 0x2, but before the instruction happens at 0x3. And yes, I understand 0x2 is unlikely, Its easier to type than the actual address

Comment: @Ex1Le: Well it confused everyone, and made everyone think you were talking about the value being stored, because it's clearly not an address.  SO gets a lot of questions from asm beginners confused about pointers vs. values...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that the question has finally been clarified by comments:

I'm not sure why you want this, or what you're hoping to gain.  Since you can apparently recompile your program with tracing code, you should just figure out how to trace what you're trying to trace.

The final address of a given line of code isn't fixed until link time, so talking about absolute addresses doesn't make sense to me.  Register allocation decisions made by compilers is also sensitive to small source changes, and optimization level.

So "ESI as set by an insn at a fixed address" is not a useful thing to record, unless the binary is already compiled, and can't be recompiled.  Even if the source was asm, you'd simply add an insn after the one you were interested in, as some *source* line, not at some binary address.

---

Your best bet is probably to use the same facilities as a debugger to stop execution at the instruction after the one you're interested in.  Record the value of ESI and then resume execution.

On Linux, you'd use the `ptrace` interface (or a library built on top of it) and set a breakpoint.  Windows obvious has some kind of API for a process to trace another process, too.  I don't know how to use either, or even what the Windows one is called, sorry.

I suspect that you'll have less code to write if you have a separate process "debug" the one you want to trace.  Having a process "debug" itself might be harder, if the APIs aren't designed for it.

Note that x86 variable-length instructions make it very complicated to programmatically find the start of the next instruction.

As I understand it, breakpoints are set by replacing the first byte of an instruction with `0xCC`, which is a special single-byte encoding of `int 3` which also has some special-case differences in execution from the `CD 03` (the two-byte form of `int 3`).

If anyone wants to improve on this answer, please edit this or copy as much as you like into your own answer.  All I can do is point the OP at debugging facilities, without any specific code suggestions.  I'm not interested enough in writing my own debugger, or finding out in more detail how it works, to go read the docs myself to solve the OP's problem.